# www. 301 redirect with parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, web

I currently use the following redirect to make the urls look nicer:

```
RewriteRule profile/(.*) index.php?id=$1
(Result: domain.co.uk/profile/00000001)
From index.php?id=00000001
```

I would like to 301 **redirect urls without www to www. and keep the above profile redirect**.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.

RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, When this is used the URL comes out like:

http://www.DOMAIN.co.uk/ **index.php** /00000001 **?id=00000001**

I’m assuming this can be done, Does this need to be bespoke for my needs or is there something im missing?

End result would ideally rewrite:

> domain.co.uk/profile/00000001

to

> www.domain.co.uk/profile/00000001

Answer (score 0):

Keep rules in correct order i.e. keep external redirects before your internal rewrites.

So this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^profile/(.+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```